# Function to return a comma delimited string

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.0

I am trying to write a function which takes a minimum of two and a maximum of six strings which should be concatenated into one comma delimited string.
Below is my latest attempt but the trailing ", " isn't being removed?

```
Private Function GetConcatenatedStrings(str1 As String, str2 As String, Optional str3 As String = "",
                            Optional str4 As String = "", Optional str5 As String = "", Optional str6 As String = "") As String
    Dim result = String.Empty
    result =
        IIf(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str1), str1 & ", ", "") &
        IIf(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str2), str2 & ", ", "") &
        IIf(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str3), str3 & ", ", "") &
        IIf(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str4), str4 & ", ", "") &
        IIf(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str5), str5 & ", ", "") &
        IIf(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str6), str6, "")
    result = result.Trim(",")
    result = result.Trim("")
    Return result
End Function
```

Potentials

```
Private Function GetConcatenatedStrings(Optional str1 As String = "", Optional str2 As String = "",
                                       Optional str3 As String = "", Optional str4 As String = "",
                                       Optional str5 As String = "", Optional str6 As String = "") As String
    Dim result = String.Empty
    Dim Strings() As String = {str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6}
    For Each value In Strings
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) Then result &= ", " + value
    Next
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result) Then
        result = result.Substring(1)
    End If
    Return result
End Function



Private Function GetConcatenatedStrings(Optional str1 As String = "", Optional str2 As String = "",
                                        Optional str3 As String = "", Optional str4 As String = "",
                                        Optional str5 As String = "", Optional str6 As String = "") As String
    Dim result = String.Empty
    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    list.Add(str1)
    list.Add(str2)
    list.Add(str3)
    list.Add(str4)
    list.Add(str5)
    list.Add(str6)
    list.RemoveAll(Function(str) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
    result = String.Join(", ", list)
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried `String.Join()`?  I might add them to a temp List, remove empty entries then Join them.  `IIF` is generally a sub optimal choice compared to the `If` operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it down to a one-liner. Try this:

```
Private Function GetConcatenatedStrings(ByVal ParamArray items() As String) As String
    Return String.Join(",", items.Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)))
End Function
```

There are two difference between this and your current code:

1. This does not require at least two strings (it would happily take zero or one, and then operate on and empty array)
2. It will allow many more than six items, if needed.

The second item is more feature than bug. If you care about the first item, you can adjust the Function signature to include the ParamArray after two "normal" string parameters, and then update the `items` list. I prefer the brevity.

Call the function like this:

```
Dim result As String = GetConcatenatedStrings("any", "number", "of", "strings", "you", "want")
```

Comment: Based on two good answers from scutch and Plutonix I've added two functions to my original answers and they both work. You like scutch have passed in a ParramArray which I haven't used before. How would the value of this argument be set with an undetermined amount of strings?

Comment: I updated my answer showing how to call the function. There are more samples on MSDN if you just search for "ParamArray". Right now, .Net allocates a new array for you behind the scenes. I've heard talk of using Span(Of T) or ValueTuple to even save that allocation and make this even better in a future .Net release.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers but I'm a real sucker for one-liners! @Joel Coehoorn

Answer (score 1):

You've got a trailing ", " with a space - not just a ","

For more flexibility give this a try...

```
Public Function GetConcatenatedStrings(ByVal ParamArray strings() As String) As String
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    For Each value In strings
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) Then result &= "," + value
    Next
    Return result.Substring(1)
End Function
```